# contact button on google map marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to have a button on the info that comes up when someone clicks a google map marker.

Im trying to have it be that when a person clicks on one of the marker locations the information that is connected with that marker pops up and then also a message button that causes a message box to pop up when clicked.

I am a super beginner but am learning and would at least be helped to even have someone tell me the exact name of the process Im trying to do even if you dont know how to do it.

Comment: You can read about this "Info window" - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Comment: You can use a way which will work as "click on a marker will unhide a button with which user can interact and clicking that button will show you the message box popup and hides the button again.And you can pass any values related to the selected marker to the popup."

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your `infowindow`, you have to pass the `content` of your `infowindow` in parameter. This is an example:

```
function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```

Here, you define a simple `map`, a simple `marker` and an `infowindow` with a huge text.

You can add a button by adding this code `<button type="button">Click Me!</button>` in the `contentString`.

Consult the [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) about `infowindows` and an example of button on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_button.asp).